# Matlab-shell autocompletion error

Tags: debugging, completion, auto-complete-mode, matlab

For some reason emacs matlab-shell is returning an error when running autocompletion. The debugging output for a completion of "load Da[TAB]" is shown below. The closest thread that I've found in sourceforge was [this](https://sourceforge.net/p/matlab-emacs/mailman/matlab-emacs-discuss/?page=1) and their solution did not work. I've also tried to reinstall matlab-mode without success. Thanks in advance for any help.

```lisp
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error #("Internal error, ’emacsdocomplete('load Da')’ returned unexpected output, \n\n  java.lang.String[]:\n\n    'Data4commQPSKRxHDL.mat'\n    'Data4commQPSKTxHDL.mat'\n    'Data_Accidental.mat'\n    'Data_Airline.mat'\n    'Data_Canada.mat'\n    'Data_Consumption.mat'\n    'Data_CorpMacro.mat'\n    'Data_CreditDefaults.mat'\n    'Data_Danish.mat'\n    'Data_DieboldLi.mat'\n    'Data_Durbin.mat'\n    'Data_EGCITest.mat'\n    'Data_EquityIdx.mat'\n    'Data_FXRates.mat'\n    'Data_GDP.mat'\n    'Data_GlobalIdx1.mat'\n    'Data_GlobalIdx2.mat'\n    'Data_GNP.mat'\n    'Data_Income1.mat'\n    'Data_Income2.mat'\n    'Data_JAustralian.mat'\n    'Data_JCITest.mat'\n    'Data_JDanish.mat'\n    'Data_MarkPound.mat'\n    'Data_NelsonPlosser.mat'\n    'Data_Overshort.mat'\n    'Data_PowerConsumption.mat'\n    'Data_Recessions.mat'\n    'Data_SchwertMacro.mat'\n    'Data_SchwertStock.mat'\n    'Data_TBill.mat'\n    'Data_TransProb.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg1.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg2.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg3.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg4.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg5.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg6.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg8.mat'\n    'Data_USEconModel.mat'\n    'Data_USEconVECModel.mat'\n    'Data_USYieldCurve.mat'\n    'data.mat'\n    'data1.mat'\n    'data10_32R.mat'\n    'data15.mat'\n    'data_mpc.mat'\n    'dataAdsbBusObjects.mat'\n    'datatip.mat'\n    'daudiosourceseparation.mat'\n\n" 34 38 (fontified t face font-lock-keyword-face) 38 41 (fontified t)))
  signal(error (#("Internal error, ’emacsdocomplete('load Da')’ returned unexpected output, \n\n  java.lang.String[]:\n\n    'Data4commQPSKRxHDL.mat'\n    'Data4commQPSKTxHDL.mat'\n    'Data_Accidental.mat'\n    'Data_Airline.mat'\n    'Data_Canada.mat'\n    'Data_Consumption.mat'\n    'Data_CorpMacro.mat'\n    'Data_CreditDefaults.mat'\n    'Data_Danish.mat'\n    'Data_DieboldLi.mat'\n    'Data_Durbin.mat'\n    'Data_EGCITest.mat'\n    'Data_EquityIdx.mat'\n    'Data_FXRates.mat'\n    'Data_GDP.mat'\n    'Data_GlobalIdx1.mat'\n    'Data_GlobalIdx2.mat'\n    'Data_GNP.mat'\n    'Data_Income1.mat'\n    'Data_Income2.mat'\n    'Data_JAustralian.mat'\n    'Data_JCITest.mat'\n    'Data_JDanish.mat'\n    'Data_MarkPound.mat'\n    'Data_NelsonPlosser.mat'\n    'Data_Overshort.mat'\n    'Data_PowerConsumption.mat'\n    'Data_Recessions.mat'\n    'Data_SchwertMacro.mat'\n    'Data_SchwertStock.mat'\n    'Data_TBill.mat'\n    'Data_TransProb.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg1.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg2.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg3.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg4.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg5.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg6.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg8.mat'\n    'Data_USEconModel.mat'\n    'Data_USEconVECModel.mat'\n    'Data_USYieldCurve.mat'\n    'data.mat'\n    'data1.mat'\n    'data10_32R.mat'\n    'data15.mat'\n    'data_mpc.mat'\n    'dataAdsbBusObjects.mat'\n    'datatip.mat'\n    'daudiosourceseparation.mat'\n\n" 34 38 (fontified t face font-lock-keyword-face) 38 41 (fontified t))))
  error("Internal error, '%s' returned unexpected output, %s" #("emacsdocomplete('load Da')" 17 21 (face font-lock-keyword-face fontified t) 21 24 (fontified t)) "\n\n  java.lang.String[]:\n\n    'Data4commQPSKRxHDL.mat'\n    'Data4commQPSKTxHDL.mat'\n    'Data_Accidental.mat'\n    'Data_Airline.mat'\n    'Data_Canada.mat'\n    'Data_Consumption.mat'\n    'Data_CorpMacro.mat'\n    'Data_CreditDefaults.mat'\n    'Data_Danish.mat'\n    'Data_DieboldLi.mat'\n    'Data_Durbin.mat'\n    'Data_EGCITest.mat'\n    'Data_EquityIdx.mat'\n    'Data_FXRates.mat'\n    'Data_GDP.mat'\n    'Data_GlobalIdx1.mat'\n    'Data_GlobalIdx2.mat'\n    'Data_GNP.mat'\n    'Data_Income1.mat'\n    'Data_Income2.mat'\n    'Data_JAustralian.mat'\n    'Data_JCITest.mat'\n    'Data_JDanish.mat'\n    'Data_MarkPound.mat'\n    'Data_NelsonPlosser.mat'\n    'Data_Overshort.mat'\n    'Data_PowerConsumption.mat'\n    'Data_Recessions.mat'\n    'Data_SchwertMacro.mat'\n    'Data_SchwertStock.mat'\n    'Data_TBill.mat'\n    'Data_TransProb.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg1.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg2.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg3.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg4.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg5.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg6.mat'\n    'Data_TSReg8.mat'\n    'Data_USEconModel.mat'\n    'Data_USEconVECModel.mat'\n    'Data_USYieldCurve.mat'\n    'data.mat'\n    'data1.mat'\n    'data10_32R.mat'\n    'data15.mat'\n    'data_mpc.mat'\n    'dataAdsbBusObjects.mat'\n    'datatip.mat'\n    'daudiosourceseparation.mat'\n\n")
  matlab-shell-completion-list(#("load Da" 0 4 (fontified t face font-lock-keyword-face) 4 7 (fontified t)))
  matlab-shell-get-completion-info()
  matlab-shell-do-completion-light()
  matlab-shell-tab()
  funcall-interactively(matlab-shell-tab)
  call-interactively(matlab-shell-tab nil nil)
  command-execute(matlab-shell-tab)
```

Furthermore, this is the error trace in the *Messages* buffer

```lisp
Company: An error occurred in auto-begin
Company: backend company-matlab-shell error "Internal error, ’emacsdocomplete('load Da')’ returned unexpected output, 

  java.lang.String[]:

    'Data4commQPSKRxHDL.mat'
    'Data4commQPSKTxHDL.mat'
    'Data_Accidental.mat'
    'Data_Airline.mat'
    'Data_Canada.mat'
    'Data_Consumption.mat'
    'Data_CorpMacro.mat'
    'Data_CreditDefaults.mat'
    'Data_Danish.mat'
    'Data_DieboldLi.mat'
    'Data_Durbin.mat'
    'Data_EGCITest.mat'
    'Data_EquityIdx.mat'
    'Data_FXRates.mat'
    'Data_GDP.mat'
    'Data_GlobalIdx1.mat'
    'Data_GlobalIdx2.mat'
    'Data_GNP.mat'
    'Data_Income1.mat'
    'Data_Income2.mat'
    'Data_JAustralian.mat'
    'Data_JCITest.mat'
    'Data_JDanish.mat'
    'Data_MarkPound.mat'
    'Data_NelsonPlosser.mat'
    'Data_Overshort.mat'
    'Data_PowerConsumption.mat'
    'Data_Recessions.mat'
    'Data_SchwertMacro.mat'
    'Data_SchwertStock.mat'
    'Data_TBill.mat'
    'Data_TransProb.mat'
    'Data_TSReg1.mat'
    'Data_TSReg2.mat'
    'Data_TSReg3.mat'
    'Data_TSReg4.mat'
    'Data_TSReg5.mat'
    'Data_TSReg6.mat'
    'Data_TSReg8.mat'
    'Data_USEconModel.mat'
    'Data_USEconVECModel.mat'
    'Data_USYieldCurve.mat'
    'dataAdsbBusObjects.mat'
    'datatip.mat'
    'daudiosourceseparation.mat'

" with args (prefix)
user-error: Cannot complete at point
```